# How do I compare a ratio in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, declaration

I have two integer values in 2 columns in excel. I need to retrieve these integers and form a ratio and then compare it with another ratio in another column.

For example, if the numbers are 2 and 3 in columns A1 & B1. I need to retrieve these values and form 2:3 in C1 and should compare if this is same as in D1 (with value 4:1).

How do i do it in VBA ?

I created a formula in C1 as =A1&":"&B1 and got the values in C1. However i am unable to compare this with the value in D1, and I am not sure how do I declare this variable in VBA ?
Kindly help me here.

Comment: have you try my answer ?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response matzone !!!  Your answer helped me in resolving my issue !!! Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this ..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim y As Integer

y = Target.Row
Select Case Target.Column
  Case 1, 2 ' if col A
    If IsEmpty(Cells(y, 1)) Or IsEmpty(Cells(y, 2)) Then
      Cells(y, 3) = ""
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Cells(y, 3) = "'" & Cells(y, 1) & ":" & Cells(y, 2)

  Case 3 ' then compare
    MsgBox IIf(Cells(y, 3) = Cells(y, 4), "Equal", "Not Equal")

End Select

End Sub
```

This use `'` sign to avoid autoconvert value to time and for this you should have in D column with `'` too ..

Answer (score 0):

If D1 is formatted in the same way as C1 then a formula of `=(D1=C1)` would return TRUE or FALSE. In VBA this could be stored in a variable:

```
Dim blnSame As Boolean
blnSame = (Range("D1").Value = Range("C1").Value)
```

---

Based on the OPs further comment, an Excel formula would be:

```
=IF(Sheet1!C1=Sheet2!D1,"Win","Lose")    ' or ,"Lose","Win"
```

(adjust the cell and sheet references as necessary) which could be copied down the column.

In VBA, a formula could be inserted into a range:

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E1:E10").Formula = _ 
    "=IF(Sheet1!C1=Sheet2!D1,""Win"",""Lose"")"
```

If you want to loop down the column inserting the words "Win" or "Lose" then IMO you should study some VBA.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case D1 is located in different sheet in the same workbook. For example, my C column values are located from C65 to C 78. and in the second sheet, (to be compared) values are in D65 to D78. i jus need to write a condition in VBA to compare these two values and return Win or lose in third sheet from E 65 to E78.    I dont want to add extra column to compute =(D1=C1) and then to create a Boolean condition. Is there any way i can write a VBA code behind and have this working in excel ?     Thanks, In advance.

Comment: So what have you tried? What knowledge do you have of VBA or Excel?